# Openerp-Magento Order Import:Openerp Server Error

Tags: magento, integration, odoo

This error occurs when i try to import orders from my magento store from openerp, how can I solve it?

> Openerp->Magento(Addon Menu)->Webstore->Webstore Name->Import Orders

```
OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/magento_integration/wizard/import_orders.py", line 34, in import_orders
    cursor, user, store_view, context
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/magento_integration/magento_.py", line 608, in import_orders_from_store_view
    order_api.info(order['increment_id']), new_context
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/magento_integration/sale.py", line 179, in find_or_create_using_magento_data
    cursor, user, order_data, context
  File "/opt/openerp/web/addons/magento_integration/sale.py", line 355, in create_using_magento_data
    'name': instance.order_prefix + order_data['increment_id'],
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please, describe the process step by step. I helps people to discover what you do wrong. If you have any code, include it in your questions.

Comment: I have already connected a magento instance with openerp using openlabs openerp-magento integrator although after installation, After i configured both the openerp & Magento there seems to be the above error on trying to sync the sales order.